# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'title' not found on type business.Book

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am having trouble with getting jsp to find the property of title in the book object even though it is all public(which was the only problems I've been able to find people having)

```
Book book = new Book(bookID, title, author);

    BookDB.insert(book);

    request.setAttribute("Book", book);
```

Gets called and then:

```
${Book.title}
```

in the jsp file

This is the object code:

package business;

public class Book {

```
public static String title, author;
public static int bookID;

public Book(int bookID, String title, String author) {

    this.bookID = bookID;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;

}

public static String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public static void setTitle(String title) {
    Book.title = title;
}

public static String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public static void setAuthor(String author) {
    Book.author = author;
}

public static int getBookID() {
    return bookID;
}

public static void setBookID(int bookID) {
    Book.bookID = bookID;
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the `static` identifier.

Comment: Thank you I would of thought to remove that!!

Comment: @Austin have you solved ? or still query

Comment: removing the static fixed the problem i just cant find out how to close the question..